# Does not have a member named 'subscript'

Tags: swift

I'm building something and it all worked fine until Swift 1.2 came out. I made some changes but still have one line of code that is playing nice. I don't understand why this is breaking:

```
let swiftArray = positionDictionary.objectForKey["positions"] as? [AnyObject]
```

it gives me an error:

> '(AnyObject) -> AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

I also tried using this:

```
let swiftArray = positionDictionary.objectForKey?["positions"] as? [AnyObject]
```

but then I get an error saying:

> Operand of postfix '?' should have an optional type; type is '(AnyObject) -> AnyObject?'

I'm really confused...can anyone help?

```
func addOrbsToForeground() {


        let orbPlistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("orbs", ofType: "plist")
        let orbDataDictionary : NSDictionary? = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: orbPlistPath!)

        if let positionDictionary = orbDataDictionary {

            let swiftArray = positionDictionary.objectForKey["positions"] as? [AnyObject]

            let downcastedArray = swiftArray as? [NSArray]

            for position in downcastedArray {

                let orbNode = Orb(textureAtlas: textureAtlas)
                let x = position.objectForKey("x") as CGFloat
                let y = position.objectForKey("y") as CGFloat
                orbNode.position = CGPointMake(x,y)
                foregroundNode!.addChild(orbNode)
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`positionDictionary` is an `NSDictionary`. You can use it just like a Swift dictionary - you don't need to use `objectForKey`.

You should just use `if let` and optional casting to get the value you want, which I think is an array of `NSDictionary` since you're using `objectForKey` again later:

```
if let downcastedArray = positionDictionary["positions"] as? [NSDictionary] {

    for position in downcastedArray {
        let orbNode = Orb(textureAtlas: textureAtlas)
        let x = position["x"] as CGFloat
        let y = position["y"] as CGFloat
        orbNode.position = CGPointMake(x,y)
        foregroundNode!.addChild(orbNode)
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, `CGPointMake` is not stylistically preferred in Swift. Instead, consider using the `CGPoint` initializer:

```
orbNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
```

Comment: "Also, you shouldn't use CGPointMake in Swift" That goes a little far in my opinion. :)

Comment: @matt Thanks, I updated with a note that this is just a stylistic suggestion.

Comment: Why is the use of `CGPointMake` in Swift not stylistically preferred? Thank you.

Comment: @Unheilig it doesn't look like a [Swift Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html). It also only accepts `CGFloat` arguments, unlike the normal initializers, which can accept other types.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It cleaned up that issue..but now I have another with the initializers.